# Windows Sensor API C++ COM integration of the orientation sensor not updating regularly on Windows 10

Tags: c++, com, accelerometer, sensors, windows-10

**Overview:**

We're currently building an app that interfaces with the Windows Sensor API using the SensorManager COM. This is a C++, non-UWP project. Specifically, we're integrating with an aggregated orientation sensor (SENSOR_TYPE_AGGREGATED_DEVICE_ORIENTATION) on a Surface tablet. This works perfectly in Windows 8. We've recently upgraded our machines to Windows 10 and are now experiencing extremely slow reporting intervals from the orientation sensor. One report every ~500-1500ms, regardless of setting the SENSOR_PROPERTY_MIN_REPORT_INTERVAL, etc. Has anyone observed this behavior on Windows 10, or have a reason/solution to this issue? Thanks!

**Details:**

This is a Visual Studio 2015, C++ project using Cinder. Our sensor manager is being initialized as follows:

```
hr = ::CoCreateInstance(
    CLSID_SensorManager,
    nullptr,
    CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
    IID_PPV_ARGS( &mSensorManager ) );
```

After acquiring a collection of applicable sensors and validating, we persist our sensor, then set the event sink. Code below:

```
STDMETHODIMP OrientationSensor::OnDataUpdated( ISensor *sensor, ISensorDataReport *report )
{
    HRESULT hr;

    PROPVARIANT pvQuat;
    PropVariantInit( &pvQuat );
    hr = report->GetSensorValue( SENSOR_DATA_TYPE_QUATERNION, &pvQuat );

    if( SUCCEEDED( hr ) ) {

        if( pvQuat.vt == ( VT_VECTOR | VT_UI1 ) ) {
            float* pElement = (float*) pvQuat.caub.pElems;

            // SET orientation quaternion
            mOrientation = ci::quat( pElement[3], pElement[0], pElement[1], pElement[2] );
        }
    }

    // CLEAR prop variant
    PropVariantClear( &pvQuat );

    return hr;
}
```

AddRef(), Release() and QueryInterface() are implemented as defined in all development guides.

We *do* receive correct data, simply at slow and long intervals, regardless of settings. We're trying to understand why this is, and why we only see this on Windows 10.

To confirm that the sensor was nominal, we compiled the UWP Orientation Sample. Indeed, this reported fast and correct readings from the orientation sensor. We're specifically looking for a solution that allows us to interface with the orientation sensor, through the sensor manager COM API.

Comment: I'll punt for the silly explanation given the low odds that these code snippets ever produce a repro: did you actually put Win10 into tablet mode?

Comment: Yes, sadly to no effect.  It works as expected using XAML samples, just not over COM.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same behavior of the Acceleration sensor on my SurfacePro,
I explicitly set the sensors sensitivity property and it solved the issue.